# Change Default Language in Google

Tags: google-account, localization

All of a sudden, whenever I open any Google Page now, (whether logged in or not), it appears in the language of Hindi and I have to use Google Translator to Translate into English and use it.

How can I fix this? How can I have English as my default Language and never have any page of Google appear in any other language?

Comment: In what state are you? What languages do you speak? I'm curious if [jquery.uls](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Universal_Language_Selector/FAQ#language-territory) selects default language better: if you visit [this page for test](https://translatewiki.net) what language do you see in top bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I recommend you to start with clearing your Google cookies, since I think it can be that Google stores your language in a cookie as well.

After your did that, head over to https://www.google.com/settings/language and select your language. Normally all Google services should be in that language by default then, but I know of some that manage languages by themselves. Like f.e. the Google Play Store.

Comment: I get 404 on https://www.google.com/settings/language

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar situation, my Google Account default language settings was already set to English; there are 2 solutions to this:

**1<sup>st</sup> Solution, applies to  all Google services:**

Change the language here: https://www.google.com/settings/language, go from English to another language, confirm then revert to English again

**2<sup>nd</sup> Solution, applies to the current Google service:**

Add `?&hl=en` to the url and submit

Comment: There is a Chrome extension which automatically applies 2nd solution to all *.google.com domains: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/english-please/lkhoknaphajfjdcpnllakeglfpbbimhp

Comment: I get 404 on https://www.google.com/settings/language

Answer (score 2):

If 1<sup>st</sup> and 2<sup>nd</sup> solution of *Nabil* didn't work, verify your language settings in your web browser. In example in Chrome go to:

chrome://settings/languages and check the settings.

See:
http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Default-Language-in-Google-Chrome